# internal server Error while accessing django project

Tags: python, django, django-wsgi

I am trying to setup a python 2.7 + Django + virtualenv + mod_wsgi environment in my centos 6.3 server to run my python application through apache.
But I am getting internal error while trying to access the application through apache. The error log shows the following.

============

```
[Fri Nov 15 04:20:30 2013] [error] [client 117.201.194.54] mod_wsgi (pid=20361): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/djangosites/spark.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Fri Nov 15 04:20:30 2013] [error] [client 117.201.194.54] mod_wsgi (pid=20361): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/djangosites/spark.wsgi'.

Fri Nov 15 04:20:30 2013] [error] [client 117.201.194.54] ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

============

It is working fine when running as a test server.

======

```
(virtualenv)[root@lampserver spark]# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
Validating models...

0 errors found
November 15, 2013 - 09:15:19
Django version 1.6, using settings 'spark.settings'
Starting development server at 0.0.0.0:8080
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

====

spark.wsgi file looks like the following.

===========

```
import sys
import site
import os

vepath = '/var/www/html/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)

site.addsitedir(vepath)

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/djangosites')

new_sys_path = [p for p in sys.path if p not in prev_sys_path]

for item in new_sys_path:

    sys.path.remove(item)

sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'spark.settings'

application = WSGIHandler()
```

==============

Entries for wsgi in apache conf looks like the following

============

```
[root@lampserver djangosites]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf 


LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/djangosites/spark.wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess spark processes=5 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

WSGIProcessGroup spark

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

=================

Apache is running as user "apache".

My project files and permissions are shown below.

===========

```
root@lampserver djangosites]# pwd

var/www/html/djangosites

[root@lampserver djangosites]# ls

spark  spark.wsgi

[root@lampserver djangosites]# ll
total 8

drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Nov 15 02:38 spark

-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache  535 Nov 15 03:16 spark.wsgi

[root@lampserver djangosites]# cd spark/

manage.py  spark/     

[root@lampserver spark]# ll
total 8

-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache  248 Nov 15 02:38 manage.py

drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 15 03:05 spark

[root@lampserver spark]# cd spark/

[root@lampserver spark]# ll
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache    0 Nov 15 02:38 __init__.py

-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  136 Nov 15 02:40 __init__.pyc

-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 1969 Nov 15 02:38 settings.py

-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 2142 Nov 15 02:40 settings.pyc

-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  296 Nov 15 02:38 urls.py

-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  416 Nov 15 02:40 urls.pyc

-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache  385 Nov 15 02:38 wsgi.py

-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  589 Nov 15 02:40 wsgi.pyc
```

==================

Can anybody please identify the problem with my settings?

Regards

Comment: You're doing some very strange things with `sys.path` there, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. The error message talks about something trying to set `DEBUG=True` outside of settings itself - can you show the code that's doing that?

Comment: This might help you...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

Comment: This is not solve your problem but a advice: do not store your django project files in a published apache directory (/var/www) like tradittional web apps do, it is a security issue

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman .But I am not using any specific code here. I am just trying to make the default Django test page work. Only run django-admin.py startproject [projectname]

Answer (score 0):

Could you start trying to change your wsgi with something more simple like:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "spark.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Maybe this helps to detect the problem easier

Also use default wsgi file (`spark/wsgi.py`) instead of your `spark.wsgi`, of course by changing the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive in your apache config file. Here is an example of a simpler apache config file with your site settings, test this and let's me know:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/djangosites:/var/www/html/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/djangosites/spark/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/html/djangosites/spark>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
     </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: @user2995718 I improve and fix my answer, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `spark.wsgi` file:

```
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/djangosites/spark')
```

Since your django site is located in that directory

Comment: Thank you
Finally I got it working. I will share the contents of wsgi file and apache entries

Comment: import os

import sys

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

import site

site.addsitedir('/var/www/html/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/djangosites/spark')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'spark.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/djangosites/spark.wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess spark processes=5 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

WSGIProcessGroup spark

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

Comment: Glad to see you solved it. Please do not forget to click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.